# Is it possible to change the momentum of a system without actually doing any work on the system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, work, collision

Consider a rigid wall somewhere in free space. Now imagine two balls of the same mass and same speed headed towards the wall from two opposite directions. Now they go on to hit the wall and rebound back with the same speed as before (elastic collision). The wall does not move cause of equal and opposite forces. Now if we see clearly, in the interval during which the forces (due to collision) act on the balls,  there is literally no displacement involved, yet the momentum (here I am talking about the ball's momentum) changes.

So..., am I correct?

Another question --> If this is true, does the kinematical equation v^2 - u^2 = 2as apply in this case? See because the velocity of say, ball 1 goes from v to 0 in some finite time, so that the acceleration is finite. But applying the above mentioned equation gives the value of acceleration as infinite cause s is 0... So that means my assumption that the time taken is finite should be wrong then... and it will be 0 actually... Is it the case?

Someone please clear my doubts...

Comment: The momentum of what? The system's momentum seems to be the same before and after the collision...

Comment: Here I am talking about the ball's momentum...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the momentum of a rigid body can be changed without doing any work on it theoretically. An example of such a case is [uniform circular motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion#Uniform_circular_motion) where the body moves along a circle with constant speed. The velocity of the body is always tangent to the circle so its direction is changing, and because the body's velocity is changing its momentum is also changing. Also, since its speed is constant, the work done on the body is zero by the [work kinetic energy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work%E2%80%93energy_principle) $W = \Delta E_k = \frac{m}{2}\Delta(v^2)$.

In your example the ball must slow down to zero then return to its original speed in the opposite direction during the collision. So work is being done in that case. However the net work over the whole collision is zero since the collision is elastic and it returns to its original speed.

The equation you reference, $v^2 - v_0^2 = 2 a s$, is only true when acceleration is [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration). Which need not be the case during a [collision](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/9-2-impulse-and-collisions).

Answer (score 0):

I can't edit my previous answer due to verifying my account. Saying $s = 0$ would require the collision to be instantaneous and therefore would require an infinite force. Such a thing doesn't really exist in reality. So physically some work would need to be done over a non-zero s and non-zero time interval.

However the idea of an infinite force collision can sometimes be used as an approximation to reality, such as in the infinite square well problem.

Comment: Thanks Friend...